# Given two finite signed measures that are equal on h-intervals. Are they equal?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I come up with this question when I was trying to understand Folland's proof of Theorem 3.29.

> Theorem: if $F\in NBV$, there is a unique complex Borel measure $\mu=\mu_r+i\mu_i$ such that $F(x)=
> \mu((-\infty,x])$.

I understand why such a complex Borel measure exists, but I don't understand why it is unique. Suppose $\nu=\nu_r+i\nu_i$ is another complex measure such that $\forall x, \nu_r((-\infty, x])+i\nu_i((-\infty,x])=\nu((-\infty,x])=F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])=\mu_r((-\infty,x])+i\mu_i((-\infty,x]).$

I can then deduce that $\mu_r((-\infty, x])=\nu_r((-\infty,x])$ and $\mu_i((-\infty, x])=\nu_i((-\infty,x])$. In addition, since these measures are finite, $\mu_r$ and $\nu_r$ are equal on any h-intervals (similarly for $\mu_i$ and $\nu_i$). Thus it suffices to prove that two finite signed measures are equal if they are equal on h-intervals.


I am also happy to see any proof of the uniqueness part of Theorem 3.29 without solving my question.

Comment: Have you solved the uniqueness part? I also be confused with it.

Answer (score 1):

The intervals $(-\infty, x]$ are a $\pi$-system that generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra; thus any finite signed Borel measures agreeing on those intervals [are equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system). (Edit: the link states this for probability measures, but the same argument holds for finite signed measures, using the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.)

Comment: May you elaborate more on how I can extend it to signed measures?

Comment: @Rmal I've edited the answer, it's easier to just prove it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Since $F\in NBV$, it can be written as the difference of two bounded increasing functions. That is, there are bounded increasing $F_{j}^{\pm}$ such that $F=F_{1}^{+}+iF_{2}^{+}-F_{1}^{-}-iF_{2}^{-}$ and $F_{j}^{\pm}(-\infty)=0$. Thus, for each $F_{j}^{\pm}$ there is a unique Borel measure $\mu_{j}^{\pm}$ such that $F_{j}^{\pm}(x)=\mu_{j}^{\pm}((-\infty,x])$. Consequently, $\mu=\mu_{1}^{+}+i\mu_{2}^{+}-\mu_{1}^{-}-i\mu_{2}^{-}$ is the required unique complex Borel measure.